# How can I prevent my monitors from taking over the sound output?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have two Samsung monitors attached to a Windows 10 desktop computer. They don't have builtin speakers, but can forward the sound from HDMI. I don't want to use that feature because I have 2.1 speakers connected to the mainboard. However, the monitors frequently take over the sound output when they connect to the computer (they can also connect to my laptop). How can I fix the sound setting to always use my normal speakers as shown below and never switch to the monitors?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output device is set in the Settings:
`Settings > System > Sound`.
in the Output section you can choose the default device from the drop-down list.

But it can be reset if the devices are unplugged/plugged in.
The easiest way would to be disable the unused output devices.

To do that:

1. Right-click on the volume icon in tray, select "Open Sound
   Settings". Settings window will open. Alternatively you can get to
   the same window through the menu Settings > System > Sound.
2. In the settings window click "**Manage sound devices**"
3. In the output devices list click on each you would like to disable and click on **Disable** button.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes a monitor is seemingly found as a new device, but this method generally seems to work. Thanks

Comment: This does not work, when a driver update happens or the GPU drivers crash the monitors get added back again.

Comment: @Tom you should always disable automatic driver update to avoid unexpected incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the device from the output list doesn't always solve the problem, but it can procrastinate it until PC restart. I'd suggest to go to `Device Manager > Sound, video and game controllers`, right click on the problematic device and disable it from there.

If you can't find the name of the device, go to your audio output setting and select it, from there you should see how it is handles (e.g., monitors are usually handled with NVIDIA drivers, therefore you should disable that on Device Manager).

Comment: This seems to be the more correct solution as the accepted one will (can often) fail if you power cycle devices, dock/undock a laptop, etc. You will often end up with copies of the device in the sound devices above and have to disable it every time. Disabling the device through this method seems to fully prevent the device from returning.